# Gradle variable from another applicationId flavor

Tags: android, gradle, android-flavors

I need to build an application created with a flavor **and create a dynamic variable who points to an *applicationId* of another flavor** (Because the code of an internal library uses the applicationId of other applications) but I don't know how to do that.

Here is the sample code :

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sample.mycompany"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
    }
    qualif {
        applicationIdSuffix = ".qual"
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix = ".dev"
    }
}

flavorDimensions "client", "nature"
    productFlavors {
        ClientA {
            dimension "client"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".A"
        }
        ClientB {
            dimension "client"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".B"
        }

        NatureX {
            dimension "nature"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".X"
        }
        NatureY {
            dimension "nature"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".Y"
            // A buildconfigField variable here to get com.sample.mycompany[client].X[buildTypes]
        }
        NatureZ {
            dimension "nature"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".Z"
            // A buildConfigField variable here to get com.sample.mycompany[client].X[buildTypes]
        }
}
```

When I compile with the Build Variant : **ClientANatureYDebug**
, final *applicationId* is ***com.sample.mycompany.A.Y.dev***

I want a dynamic variable with buildConfigField (or something else to retrieve the new variable in Java) who is ***com.sample.mycompany.A.X.dev***

I think to get the **final applicationId** and replace the applicationIdSuffix of the current nature compilation dimension by .X and get the result in a new variable but I do not know how. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with :

```
buildConfigField "String", "VAL_SHARE_TO_RECEIVER_APP_ID", "APPLICATION_ID.replace(\".Y\", \".X\")"
```